# Titanium Studio - app icon not working

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

I tried  everything and my android app icon doesn't work, can anybody help me?
y tried create a new project and paste just the app folder and it still the same.
I'm using the 3.5.1 Titanium SDK.

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Agree with @Ashish. You need to put the icons in the

```
platform / android / res
```

folder. Under this folder I have a number of folders with an image named "appicon.png" in each of them:

```
drawable-hdpi
drawable-ldpi
drawable-mdpi
drawable-xhdpi
drawable-xxhdpi
drawable-xxxhdpi
```

I use [ticons](http://ticons.fokkezb.nl) by Fokke Zandbergen to generate the icons. Works like a charm :-)

On that page you can also find a link to a description about Androids 9-patch images (that you will need for different background images to scale correctly). One quick note on the splash and background images. I have put them in

```
app / assets / android / images / res-long-port-hdpi (and other resolutions)
```

And that also works well.

/John

Comment: Great Lizbeth. Then you should mark this response as the right answer for others quickly to find out ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the respective resolution appcions to the below folder structure and clean and build.

```
Platform ---> android ---> res
```

In the res folder there are resolution specific folders where you can place your appicons.

Answer (score 0):

did you every try this  :

1. open you object using titanium studio
2. open tiapp.xml and chose Overview tag
3. click Browse and choose a picture in Application icon option
4. build you project

Answer (score 0):

While you add the appicon.png in the image folders, make sure that you are also adding in the folder:

```
app -> platform -> android -> res -> (hdpi folder)
```

Otherwise, it shows the default titanium app-icon.